# cron from multiple files

Tags: cron

How do I make cron daemon  check cron entries from more than one files.
In my project I need to frequently update cron file, so instead of manipulating the existing file I was planning to write my project cron entries in a dedicated cron file.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/391246/multiple-crontabs-for-one-user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users have 3 options:

1. Access their own crontab entry using the command `crontab -e`.
2. If they have `sudo` privileges on the system they can add crontab files to the /etc/cron.d directory.
3. Add scripts to one of these directories:

   - /etc/cron.daily
   - /etc/cron.hourly
   - /etc/cron.monthly
   - /etc/cron.weekly

Answer (score 3):

You can put a file for you application only in `/etc/cron.d`.